# Creating a ClassLoader to load a JAR file from a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, jar, classloader

I'm looking to write a custom class loader that will load a `JAR` file from across a custom network. In the end, all I have to work with is a byte array of the `JAR` file.

I cannot dump the byte array onto the file system and use a `URLClassLoader`.
My first plan was to create a `JarFile` object from a stream or byte array, but it only supports a `File` object.

I've already written up something that uses a `JarInputStream`:

```
public class RemoteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private final byte[] jarBytes;

    public RemoteClassLoader(byte[] jarBytes) {
        this.jarBytes = jarBytes;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> clazz = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (clazz == null) {
            try {
                InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(name.replace('.', '/') + ".class");
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                StreamUtils.writeTo(in, out);
                byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
                clazz = defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                if (resolve) {
                    resolveClass(clazz);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                clazz = super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
        }
        return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResource(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        try (JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(jarBytes))) {
            JarEntry entry;
            while ((entry = jis.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.getName().equals(name)) {
                    return jis;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This may work fine for small `JAR` files, but I tried loading up a `2.7MB` jar file with almost `2000` classes and it was taking around `160 ms` just to iterate through all the entries let alone load the class it found.

If anyone knows a solution that's faster than iterating through a `JarInputStream`'s entries each time a class is loaded, please share!

Comment: I inherited a similar class loader in a project I used to work on. It was extremely slow there too. Aside from that it caused me all sorts of headaches. In the end the lesson learned was not use a custom class loader unless you really need to.

Comment: I have to ask... what is wrong with storing it in a file? I mean, the Jars could be of arbitrary size, it sounds like a really bad idea to keep all the loaded Jars in the memory forever. It also mean you'll keep the Jar bytes, the cached entries plus the loaded classes... you pay the penalty 3 times.

Comment: @wyr0 you also expect an answer that don't store the content of your jar into the file system either even if it is much much faster and scalable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would iterate through the class once and cache the entries.  I would also look at the source code for URLClassLoader to see how it does it.  If that fails, write the data to a temporary file and load it via the normal class loader.

Comment: I was considering caching the entries like you suggest. And I guess it wouldn't take up anymore space than what's already being used by the JAR byte array. I took a look in the URLClassLoader but it's using a URLClassPath delegate that's implemented in the Sun package. I guess I'll go with the caching idea. Thanks.

Comment: It should use more space than the original as it is compressed.  It shouldn't be too much more.

Answer (score 8):

#### The best you can do

First you have no need to use `JarInputStream` as it only adds the support of the manifest to the class `ZipInputStream` which we don't really care here. You cannot put your entries into a cache (unless you store directly the content of each entries which would be terrible in term of memory consumption) because a `ZipInputStream` is not meant to be shared so it cannot be read concurrently. The best you can do is to store the name of the entries into a cache to only iterate over the entries when we know that the entry exists.

**The code could be something like this:**

```
public class RemoteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private final byte[] jarBytes;
    private final Set<String> names;

    public RemoteClassLoader(byte[] jarBytes) throws IOException {
        this.jarBytes = jarBytes;
        this.names = RemoteClassLoader.loadNames(jarBytes);
    }

    /**
     * This will put all the entries into a thread-safe Set
     */
    private static Set<String> loadNames(byte[] jarBytes) throws IOException {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        try (ZipInputStream jis = 
             new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(jarBytes))) {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = jis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                set.add(entry.getName());
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        // Check first if the entry name is known
        if (!names.contains(name)) {
            return null;
        }
        // I moved the JarInputStream declaration outside the
        // try-with-resources statement as it must not be closed otherwise
        // the returned InputStream won't be readable as already closed
        boolean found = false;
        ZipInputStream jis = null;
        try {
            jis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(jarBytes));
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = jis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.getName().equals(name)) {
                    found = true;
                    return jis;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Only close the stream if the entry could not be found
            if (jis != null && !found) {
                try {
                    jis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignore me
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### The ideal solution

Accessing to a zip entry using `JarInputStream` is clearly not the way to do it as you will need to iterate over the entries to find it which **is not a scalable approach** because the performance will depend on total amount of entries in your jar file.

To get the best possible performances, you need to use a [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) in order to **access directly to an entry** thanks to the method [`getEntry(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry-java.lang.String-) whatever the size of your archive. Unfortunately the class `ZipFile` doesn't provide any constructors that accept the content of your archive as a `byte` array (it is not a good practice anyway as you could face OOME if the file is too big) but only as a `File`, so you will need to change the logic of your class in order to store the content of your zip into a temporary file, then provide this temporary file to your `ZipFile` to be able to access to the entry directly.

**The code could be something like this:**

```
public class RemoteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private final ZipFile zipFile;

    public RemoteClassLoader(byte[] jarBytes) throws IOException {
        this.zipFile = RemoteClassLoader.load(jarBytes);
    }

    private static ZipFile load(byte[] jarBytes) throws IOException {
        // Create my temporary file
        Path path = Files.createTempFile("RemoteClassLoader", "jar");
        // Delete the file on exit
        path.toFile().deleteOnExit();
        // Copy the content of my jar into the temporary file
        try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jarBytes)) {
            Files.copy(is, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        return new ZipFile(path.toFile());
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        // Get the entry by its name
        ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(name);
        if (entry != null) {
            // The entry could be found
            try {
                // Gives the content of the entry as InputStream
                return zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Could not get the content of the entry
                // you could log the error if needed
                return null;
            }
        }
        // The entry could not be found
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you save the file as temporary, you can than just use the standard URLClassloader, can't you?

Comment: @JanCetkovsky that's correct but it is not what the OP wants, I quote "I cannot dump the byte array onto the file system and use a URLClassLoader."

Comment: What I meant was that your 'ideal solution' could be in that case simplified by extending the UrlClassLoader (as you dump the file there anyway).

Comment: @JanCetkovsky probably yes, but here the idea was to show the main difference in more details between the 2 approaches, the first one with a time complexity of `O(n)` and the other one with a time complexity of `O(1)`