# Can you use a Pack200 file without first unpacking it?

Tags: java, jar, classloader

Is it possible to load classes on-the-fly (in memory) from a pack.gz file created by [Pack200](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/pack200.html) without unpacking it back into a jar first? All of the examples that I can find just show me how to unpack it into a .jar file and then load the classes from the .jar file.

Comment: Yes, and this is routinely done with JWS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible.  The [Pack200.Unpacker.unpack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/jar/Pack200.Unpacker.html#unpack-java.io.InputStream-java.util.jar.JarOutputStream-) method writes to a JarOutputStream;  if you do that in a background thread, you can connect a new JarOutputStream to a JarInputStream using a pipe, and read from that.

```
public JarInputStream readPackFile(Path packGzFile)
throws IOException {

    PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream(pipeIn);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Callable<Void> unpacker = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call()
        throws IOException {
            try (InputStream file =
                    new GZIPInputStream(
                        new BufferedInputStream(
                            Files.newInputStream(packGzFile)));
                 JarOutputStream jarOutput = new JarOutputStream(pipeOut)) {

                Pack200.newUnpacker().unpack(file, jarOutput);
                return null;
            } finally {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    };
    executor.submit(unpacker);

    return new JarInputStream(pipeIn);
}
```

That *should* be sufficient.  However, there are still two issues:

- If there’s an error with the unpack operation, you’ll never know about it, since ExecutorServices suppress their taskṣ’ exceptions.
- JarInputStream and JarOutputStream (more specifically, their superclasses, InflaterInputStream and DeflaterOutputStream) don’t work well with pipes.  This is because closing the JarOutputStream forces a call to its [finish()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#finish--) method, but the JarInputStream on the other side of the pipe will never read that data.  This means the JarInputStream will almost certainly be closed before `finish()` is called, causing `finish()` to generate an IOException due to a broken pipe.

To resolve the first problem, we can override the JarInputStream’s `close` method to account for any failure in the unpack operation.  To resolve the second, we can override `finish()` in the JarOutputStream to do nothing:

```
public JarInputStream readPackFile(Path packGzFile)
throws IOException {

    PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream(pipeIn);

    class NonFinishingJarOutputStream
    extends JarOutputStream {
        NonFinishingJarOutputStream(OutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        public void finish()
        throws IOException {
            // Deliberately empty.
        }
    }

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Callable<Void> unpacker = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call()
        throws IOException {
            try (InputStream file =
                    new GZIPInputStream(
                        new BufferedInputStream(
                            Files.newInputStream(packGzFile)));
                 JarOutputStream jarOutput =
                    new NonFinishingJarOutputStream(pipeOut)) {

                Pack200.newUnpacker().unpack(file, jarOutput);
                return null;
            } finally {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    };
    Future<?> unpackerTask = executor.submit(unpacker);

    return new JarInputStream(pipeIn) {
        @Override
        public void close()
        throws IOException {
            super.close();
            try {
                // If the unpack generated an exception, propagate it here.
                unpackerTask.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                InterruptedIOException iie = new InterruptedIOException();
                iie.initCause(e);
                throw iie;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That gives me a JarInputStream, not a JarFile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602668/creating-a-classloader-to-load-a-jar-file-from-a-byte-array seems to indicate that it's difficult at best to actually do much with a JarInputStream.

Comment: All JarFile constructors require a file.  I’m pretty sure there is no way to use the JarFile class without one.